# SQL Lite Storage sometimes return null ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

I’m building an app in multiple languages
I’m using SQL Storage lite for keeping the chosen language
but sometimes the storage returns null

```
<ion-item class="settings-items" no-border ion-item>
  <ion-icon class="img-view" item-start name="ios-globe">
  </ion-icon>
  <ion-label [ngClass]="(this.Platform.isRTL ) ? 'settings-textAr': 'settings-text' ">{{'LANG' | translate}}</ion-label>
  <ion-select mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="lang" item-end (ionChange)="switchLanguage()">
    <ion-option class="options" value="en" [selected]="lang === english">
      English
    </ion-option>
    <ion-option class="options" value="ar" [selected]="lang === arabic">
      العربية
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

select lang

```
  switchLanguage() {
if (this.lang === 'en') {

  this.translate.use(this.lang)
  this.Platform.setDir('ltr', true)
  this.storage.set('DocLang' , JSON.stringify(this.lang))
} else {

  this.Platform.setDir('rtl', true)
  this.translate.use(this.lang);
  this.storage.set('DocLang' , JSON.stringify(this.lang))

}
```

getting the language and setting it with the direction

```
this.Storage.get('DocLang').then((val) => {
      this.lang = JSON.parse(val)

      console.log(this.lang)
      if (this.lang === 'en') {
        this.TranslateService.use('en');
        this.platform.setDir('ltr', true);

      } else if(this.lang === 'ar'){
        this.TranslateService.use('ar');
        this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);

      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to store key value pair, SQLite is not the right choice as its relational database. Please refer to the following question:

[saving and retrieving key-value pairs in an sqlite database android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230127/saving-and-retrieving-key-value-pairs-in-an-sqlite-database-android)

The one easy way is store your language in local or session storage. I have implemented the multi language support in my application as follows:

[Multi language support without plugin in ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159180/multi-language-support-without-plugin-in-ionic-app)

To store language in local storage use following code:

```
setLanguage(languageCode : string){
    localStorage.setItem('language',languageCode);
  }
```

Comment: I would store the object or array in a file using the Cordova plugin. That way I know it will always bring what I want.